# Unix file read from specific position onwards

Tags: bash, unix

I've a unix text file and I want to search from a specific pattern. When I find the first occurrence of the pattern, from that position onward, I want to read complete file till end.

How I can achieve this via bash commands.
Regards,

DKamran

Comment: an example would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

```
seq 15 | sed '0,/4/d'
```

Will delete up to the first `4` and print the rest.

Comment: Beautiful. I've gotten used to thinking of `sed` as just a search and replace tool.

Comment: However, the `0,` part of the address is not portable e.g. to BSD `sed`.  A simple portable (I hope!) workaround would be `sed -n -e '1,/4/d' -e p`

Answer (score 1):

`perl -ne 'if (/your_pattern/..EOF){print}' your_file.txt`

This uses the flip flop operator so that it ignores every line until your pattern is matched. Until it reaches the end of the file, it prints each line.

Comment: EOF is actually redundant here - it's just evaluating as true. So /your_pattern/..1 would also work.

Answer (score 1):

awk variant:

```
$ seq 1 15 | awk '/6/{t=1}t'
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Answer (score -2):

grep for the pattern Using the `-n` option to get the line number. Cut out the line number using `awk` or `cut` and then use `tail` with the `-n` option and a `+` suffixed with the line number you've obtained to give you the file from that point onwards.

Comment: That's pretty bass-ackwards. Generally, finding a line number so you can do a second pass with that information should be avoided when a single pass is enough.

Comment: You're right. My bad. But then again, everything I do in shell is quick, dirty and disposable.